# How do I install Firefox Developer Edition on ElementaryOS?

Tags: firefox

The download link on the Firefox Developer Edition page just downloads a .tar.bz2 file.

Have tried the following methods:

**Umake**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
umake web firefox-dev
```

This gave me:

```
ERROR: Download page changed its syntax or is not parsable
```

**APT**

I used:

```
sudo apt install firefox-dev
```

The command ran but i could not find any instance of firefox developer edition in application launcher search. I ended up using `sudo apt remove` later.

**PPA**

Upon running `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora`, I got the error:

`sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found`

I also tried to install it manually from the .tar.bz2 file, but it was confusing as there are no elementary-specific instructions on the web.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to manual install it.

**1.** Download from the official website: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/

I got the **firefox-62.0b20.tar.bz2**

**2.** Uncompress the archive content somewhere, you can use `~/.opt/firefox` or `Downloads/apps` it's your call.

**3.** inside the firefox directory there's a firefox file. Right-click -> Permissions -> Execute. Now you will be able to execute it.

**4.** Click (or double-click) the firefox file, it will start firefox.

If you don't want it anymore or want to download a different version just delete the directory and repeat the process. You can create a Launcher shortcut though.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora
sudo apt update
sudo apt install firefox-dev
```

This will get you the Aurora builds, not stable. It looks like that's what you were wanting to do?

Comment: I actually wanted the stable build, but the only instructions for PPA pointed to the aurora builds. Thanks for the answer though!